# Django no muestra template personalizado

Tags: python, django

Estoy creando una aplicación con Django y quiero modificar el template change_form.html de uno de mis modelos. Tal y como he visto en la documentación he creado el mismo archivo en:
/miSitio/templates/admin/miapp/mimodelo/change_form.html

Dentro del archivo change_form.html he incluido el código:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}{{ block.super }}
   <h1>Mi modelo</h1>
   Print my model here {{ original }}
   Print foreignkey related records of my model:
   {% for item in original.items_set.all %} {{ item }} {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Pero no hay forma... Sigue apareciendo el template por defecto de Django. Tengo que modificar algun archivo más?

Gracias por la ayuda!